# Showing 3 ListPlots in a single 3D Plot

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I have three ListPlots given by

```
`ListPlot[Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi], 0.1}]]
ListPlot[Table[{x, Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi], 0.1}]]
ListPlot[Table[{x, Exp[ x]}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi], 0.1}]]`
```

I want to display all the three in a single 3D Plot with (say) x=axis showing `x`, y-axis showing curve number: 1 for Sin[x], 2 for Cos[x] and 3 for Exp[x], and z-axis displaying the functions themselves. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
funcs = {Sin, Cos, Exp};
tbl = Table[Table[{x, i, funcs[[i]][x]}, {x, 0, 2 π, 0.1}], {i, 3}];

ListPointPlot3D[tbl, BoxRatios -> 1, PlotLegends -> funcs]
```

[image]

Comment: An alternative: `tbl = MapIndexed[Map[Insert[First[#2], 2], #1] &, Table[{x, funcs[x]}, {funcs, {Sin, Cos, Exp}}, {x, 0, 2 π, 0.1}]]`

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to start the Ticks from 0 in the plot. I mean instead of 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5,3.0 marking the axis, can be have 0.0, 0.5, 1.0,1.5,2.0?

Comment: @Rob, you only need to shift. Spot the difference: `tbl = MapIndexed[Map[Insert[First[#2] - 1, 2], #1] &, Table[{x, funcs[x]}, {funcs, {Sin, Cos, Exp}}, {x, 0, 2 π, 0.1}]]`. If you wish to stick with kglr's approach: `tbl = Table[Table[{x, i - 1, funcs[[i]][x]}, {x, 0, 2 π, 0.1}], {i, 3}]`.